# Get attribute values using xpath in SQL Server 2012

Tags: sql-server, xpath, xquery

I am using SQL Server 2012. I have the following code

```
DECLARE @x xml
SET @x = '<labels defaultText = "Javascript">      
            <label text = "Asp" />      
            <label text = "Sql" />      
            <label text = "Wcf" />
          </labels>'
```

I want to write xpath/xquery query to get all attributes' values named text (in this example - "AspSqlWcf").

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like this

```
DECLARE @x xml
SET @x = '<labels defaultText = "Javascript">      
            <label text = "Asp" />      
            <label text = "Sql" />      
            <label text = "Wcf" />
          </labels>'  
SELECT (SELECT 
C.value('@text','nvarchar(100)') 
FROM @x.nodes('labels/label') as T(C)
FOR XML PATH(''),TYPE).value('.','nvarchar(MAX)') as val
```